# Extracting a matrix at specified indices from a bigger Mat in openCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a matrix A

A =

```
 1     2     3     4     5
 6     7     8     9    10
11    12    13    14    15
16    17    18    19    20
```

i have another matrix to specify the indices

index =

```
 1     2
 3     4
```

And now i want to create a matrix `Mat C` which consists of pixels having the value corresponded to the values specified by `Mat index`

**Task:** I need to get `Mat C` using **openCV** which should look like following:

C =

```
 1     6
11    16
```

**PS:** It is similar to the MatLab function `C = A(index)`

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV, it's easier to extract a sub-matrix instead of several specific indexes. For example, if you want to get a sub-matrix, in you example, say

```
 7     8     9  
12    13    14
```

You can simply use

```
Rect roi(1, 1, 3, 2);    // x, y, width, height
Mat sub_mat = mat(roi);
```

---

To get the values that are from several specific indexes, you may need to loop the indexes to achieve the goal. In OpenCV, you can access the element of a matrix by using [`Mat::at()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) function.

```
float value = mat.at<float>(2, 3);  // value at 3th row, 4th col, i.e. '14'
```

A better way is that you can define a mask matrix to specify what values you want and then you can call [`Mat::copyTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto):

```
inputMat.copyTo(outputMat, maskMat);
```

[image]

Comment: I can't use `ROI` because the indices are scattered in my case and don not represent a region of the image. Secondly, to define a mask, my problem remains the same...how would i specify the pixels where the value of mask should be 1/255 using my scattered indices. And Lastly, using the pixel by pixel method, i need to specify (row,Col) but i just have single indices

Comment: @user2756695 You can easily get the row and col indexes based on the single index by divide/module.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by making  the combination [Mat::col()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-col), [Mat::clone()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-clone), [Mat::reshape()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape) as follows,

Your input Mat

```
Mat A=(Mat_<uchar>(4,5)<<  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,\
                           6,  7,  8,  9, 10,\
                          11, 12, 13, 14, 15,\
                          16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
```

**1. [Mat::col()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-col)+[Mat::clone()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-clone)**

Create a new header for any  column using your index

```
Mat B = A.col(0).clone(); //Will give you 0-th column
```

the result will be a column Mat with four rows and one column like

```
     [ 1  ]
     | 6  |
  B= | 11 |
     [ 16 ]
```

**2.[Mat::reshape()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape)**

Now reshape your Mat using the following code, note that your source Mat rows should be divisible by 2 so that you will get square Mat as result

```
B=B.reshape(0,B.rows/2);
```

will give you the result..

```
B = [ 1   6  ]
    [ 11  16 ]
```

Comment: Not a general approach to me. How about the indexes become `3 6 12 14`?

Comment: You can access any column by just giving the index like  `Mat B = A.col(index).clone();` will works on top row, but I couldn’t get your question for the index other than top row.